# Partitioning with constraints of edge weighted graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, weighted

I have an edge weighted connected graph. It is not a directed one. My task is to remove a few edges so that the graph become divided into at least two half and the sum of weights of the removed edges has to be the least possible. 
I know how to find the minimum path between any vertices, I think it has to help somehow, but still I cannot come up with any good idea. If anyone knows advise me plese the algorithm of solving the problem.

Comment: Take a look at [Karger's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karger's_algorithm).

Comment: Oh. Thank you a lot. I hope it will help. And now it is the time to implement.

Comment: [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) implements a lot of common graph problems and has a nice API, including [minimum_cut](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.flow.minimum_cut.html).